# How do I program Alveo X3522 Smart NIC card to allow FPGA onboard to access the network through the NIC?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, openonload

x3522 is really new and there are so little resources such as examples, unlike alveo u50 u250. How can I interface the FPGA with the network interface logic on the alveo x3522 to archieve automated network reply based on incoming network traffic?

I have tried to read up on the Xilinx documentation on `ef_vi` and `openonload` and there is almost no mention of FPGA at all!

Comment: Hey, is this a programming question? If it isn't, then we're the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Oh is it? Is there any suggestions for FPGA related questions? Of course it is programming related but the line is blur, cuz it's FPGA on Smart NIC.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I chose to ask rather than vote to close. Blurry lines are ok :)

Comment: hi @Kimlim, have you managed to get any documentation from amd/xilinx?

Answer (score 0):

Onload/ef_vi doesn’t run on an FPGA but has the ability to work with an FPGA to reduce latency using the Delegated Sends API, as described in the Onload User Guide.

The X3522 uses an FPGA for its logic and the X3522 does have a section about a hybrid mode. I’d recommend raising the request with the support team who handle the card who would be able to give you more detailed information. The address to use for this is support-nic@amd.com

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am looking for a way to let the Programmable logic (FPGA chip) to take in (and send out) network streams to the NIC logic, do you have a suggestion on how I can word my question better?

Comment: I don't see any issue with the question wording. If you email the support team they will be able to ask about any points that aren't clear.